# Hyperlinks returning 404's

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm very new to Cognito Forms and I'm setting up my first form. I'm wanting to create a link to `www.bit.ly/1xmHejd/`. To do so, I create a Content field and used the Insert/Edit Link button. These are the settings for it:

[image: Picture]

After all that is done, I went to a live version of the form and clicked the link to make sure it is working. However, when clicking the link, it redirects me to `https://www.cognitoforms.com/%22http://www.bit.ly/1xmHejd/%22` instead of just `http://www.bit.ly/1xmHejd/`. How do I remove the Cognito Forms portion of the URL? Is it possible?

Comment: I am a developer for Cognito Forms, we have not been able to reproduce this issue on with the information we have. Could you submit a support ticket so that we can take a closer look at your form.

Answer (score -1):

It looks from the URL generated as if there is a space in front of the URL that you're entering.

Often a blank space is represented by `%22` in URLs.

First thing I'd check is that there's not been an extra space pasted in there by accident.

Comment: %22 is the code for a double quote ("). From the screenshot William is showing no double quote in front of his link, so this does not really make a lot of sense.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. %20 is a space. I thought I was on to something there :/